# Can I send # as a part of URL?

Tags: url, character-encoding

I am sending commands through a WEB server.Commands' URL format has "&text=mycommand" in it.
Example
*myurl*&text=AT#123
The problem is my commands have to have # in them. This is the protocol the receiving device understands.
Is there a way to accomplish it?
The part after # is cut, I guess it's because it is treated as section identifier.
Thanks.
Kirill.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `#` with `%23`.

See [this list](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html) for more information.

Comment: I tried it, but it is translated back to # and treated the same.